# a screencast key add-on that displays combination keys like g+x or g+z etc

Tags: objects

I am looking for a screencast key add-on that displays combination keys like g+x or g+z etc. Unfortunately, the four add-ons I found so far only display g and not the following axis key.

I am using the latest version of blender.

Thank you very much in advance.

All the best, Michael

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on Linux, try a key-mon - small but versatiles app to show multiple pressed keys, easily configurable.

See https://code.google.com/archive/p/key-mon/